# How to fix the error object is possibly null or undefined using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi i have data like below when logged to browser console,

```
data **** {progressValue: {...}}
```

and looks like below

```
progress {
    completed: "10",
    total: "20",
}
```

i want to check if completed value is greater than or equal to total value then stop polling.

below is the code,

```
I have defined progress type for query like so 

type progress {
    completed: String
    total: String 
}  

async Progress(id: 
    QueryCheckArgs['id']) {
        const { data } = await this.get(
        `/${BASE_PATH}/${id}/progress/`
        );
        const output = {
            completed: data.connectivity_test_completed_if,
            total: data.connectivity_test_total_if,
        }; 
        return output;
    }


const Component = () => {
     const {
         data: progressValue,
         startPolling: startPolling,
     } = useProgress({
         variables: { id },
         fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
     });
     if (progressValue) {
         if (progressValue.progress.completed >= 
         progressValue.progress.total) { //error here says object 
         //is 
    //possibly null or undefined
         setProgress(undefined);
         stopPolling();
     }
  }
```

}

how can i rewrite above condition such that error object is possibly undefined or null is fixed.also what should be the type of progress now thanks.

Comment: Share interface or type of data you are receiving?

Comment: i have shared how the data looks when i log in browser console and when i expand the data. i dont know its type. still a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not defined any data type so try using [Object Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
if (progressValue?.progress?.completed >= progressValue?.progress?.total)
```

Comment: it says completed and total type doesnt exist in query